can't connect to neo4j database with Neo4jGraph but works with GraphDatabase.driver
With this code on a notebook in vscode in wsl:
graph = Neo4jGraph(
        url="bolt://localhost:7687",
        username="neo4j",
        password="neo4j",
        # enhanced_schema=True,
        # sanitize=True,
    )
schema = graph.schema
for type in query_types:
    print(type)
    instructions = f"{type}: {query_types[type]}"
    values = graph.query(
            """MATCH (n)
WHERE rand() > 0.6
WITH n LIMIT 2
CALL {
    WITH n
    MATCH p=(n)-[*3..3]-()
    RETURN p LIMIT 1
}
RETURN p"""
        )
questions = chain.invoke(
    {"input": schema, "instructions": instructions, "values": values}
)

I get:

While using this works :
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "neo4j"))

Here is my terminal where I launch the database, everything looks fine:

Thanks for your help by advance

can you try replacing url="bolt://localhost:7687" INTO  url="neo4j://localhost:7687"? Thanks.

well in fact it was because my jupyter notebook was running on wsl while my neo4j database was running on windows prompt XD, thanks for your reply though

glad that it worked out for you. thanks

post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly .
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
how to ask

Since you found the cause (and presumably a solution), you should create an Answer to help others with same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

As stated above in fact it was because my jupyter notebook was running on wsl while my neo4j database was running on windows prompt, so I guess both should be on the same system
